# How do insert comma separated values from columns in the same table?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, sql-insert

This is my table that I have. I want to Insert comma separated values from tag_title column to tagList column matching the fk_ContentDataID which is unique. 
Can I do it on MySQL or do I need a PHP Script for this.

```
**fk_contentDataID             fk_tagID       tag_title                  tagList**
68                                 789          ANGELINA JOLIE              NULL
1325                               789          ANGELINA JOLIE              NULL  
1986                               789          ANGELINA JOLIE              NULL  
2052                               789          ANGELINA JOLIE              NULL  
2145                               789          ANGELINA JOLIE              NULL
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE Table SET tagList = REPLACE(tag_title,' ',',');
```

Hope this is what you were looking for